# How to get Authentication Users list from firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a firebase project, it authenticates users mobile number to login

I need to fetch all mobiles number using node js SDK

```
const fs = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/john/Downloads/adminsdk.json");

fs.initializeApp({
 credential: fs.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

I have setup the fire base like this, not able to understand how to fetch data, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are yuo looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all authenticated users try to use this

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/john/Downloads/adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: fs.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const users = admin.auth().listUsers();
```

by default, listUsers() method will return up to 1000 user

if you have more than 1000 users, listUsers() method will return a list of users, and pageToken you can get the second 1000 like that

```
users = admin.auth().listUsers(1000,pageToken);
```

For more information, you can check the firebase admin documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthlistusers